# Using Aurelia validation addObject and removeObject when swapping model

Tags: aurelia

I'm running into problems using Aurelia Validation with dynamically built validation rules.  I was successful (but not so elegant) in creating the rules dynamically based on the validation property of an array of form controls, like this:

```
ctrlAccountSettings = [
  {label: 'Code', type: 'my-textbox', bind: 'acc_code', validation: '.required().minLength(17).maxLength(30)'},
  {label: 'Name_orig', type: 'my-textbox', bind: 'acc_name_orig', validation: '.required().minLength(3).maxLength(100)'},
  {label: 'Name_tran', type: 'my-textbox', bind: 'acc_name_tran', validation: '.minLength(3).maxLength(100)'},
  {label: 'Description', type: 'my-textarea', rows: '3', bind: 'acc_description', validation: '.maxLength(255)'},
  {label: 'Status', type: 'my-dropdown', bind: 'acc_status', enum: 'ActiveInactive', validation: '.required()'}];
```

And this code to create/apply the rules in my view-model:

```
attached() {
  // define rules based on controls
  this.rules = [];
  this.controls.map(control => {
    if (control.validation) {
      if (control.validation.match(/\.required\(\)/)) { this.rules.push(ValidationRules.ensure(control.bind).required().rules[0]); }
      let minLength = control.validation.match(/\.minLength\(([0-9]+)\)/);
      if (minLength) { this.rules.push(ValidationRules.ensure(control.bind).minLength(minLength[1]).rules[0]); }
      let maxLength = control.validation.match(/\.maxLength\(([0-9]+)\)/);
      if (maxLength) { this.rules.push(ValidationRules.ensure(control.bind).maxLength(maxLength[1]).rules[0]); }
    }
  });
  // initialize modelEdit and add validation rules
  this.modelEdit = {};
  // this.validationCtrl.removeAllObjects();            doesn't exist
  // this.validationCtrl.removeObject(this.modelEdit);  doesn't work
  // this.validationCtrl.destroy();                     not sure how to recover from this
  this.validationCtrl.addObject(this.modelEdit, this.rules);
}
```

The problem is that as this same component is re-attached several times, I get duplicate rules lingering that prevent the form from being validated.

**Question 1 (most important): How do I use `removeObject()` or a similar method to clean up previous validation?**

**Question 2:** Is there a better way to apply the validation rules from my array of control objects dynamically?  I don't like having to create a `this.rules.push()` option for *every* type of rule.

**Question 3:** My controls aren't changing.  Is there a better way to keep the rules in place even when the object is swapped out?

Comment: Here's a gist you can use to create a reproduction of your issue: https://gist.run/?id=381fdb1a4b0865a4c25026187db865ce

Comment: Thanks.  Here's an approximation of what I'm trying to do.  It looks like the main problem I was experiencing is corrected by adding a `controller.reset()` before swapping the entity. But that doesn't answer questions 2 and 3.  Any ideas or suggestions looking at my code? https://gist.run/?id=22f17210934d436e231b223b235fcd32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

When you call `controller.validate()` with no args, the controller will validate all objects you've given it via `addObject`. Based on the UI in [your gist](https://gist.run/?id=22f17210934d436e231b223b235fcd32), it seems like you need to call `removeObject` to remove the previously added object before adding a new object instance in your `goCreate` or `goEdit` methods. [Here's an example](https://gist.run/?id=72f8c950fca91ebb677439d20f8eade2). Without calling `removeObject` (or `reset`) the controller thinks it still needs to validate the previously added object(s).

**Answer to question 2**

We're looking at ways to improve the process for adding creating rules from data. Here's an alternative approach:
https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/363

Here's the issue for enhancing the API for this:
https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/400

**Answer to question 3**

Your gist makes the association between the object and it's rules by passing both the object and the rules to `controller.addObject`. That's the best way to do it when you're using `addObject`. That said, you probably don't need to use addObject. Your code might be simpler if you remove the `addObject` / `reset` code and specify the rules in your bindings [like this](https://gist.run/?id=984e2d89911155e6b767b41632eba6b0). This will cause the controller to use the default behavior which only validates objects+properties currently used in `& validate` bindings.

Comment: Thanks sooo much! I appreciate you taking the time to give me an expert answer. I appreciate all that has already gone into making tools like Aurelia-validation and am confident it will continue to gain more and more support!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `reset()` also remove all objects or simply clear the current validation messages while leaving the rules in place?

Comment: Clears without removing the object(s) it's been given. Reset is intended to be the opposite of validate.

Comment: One final question while I have your attention. I like your proposed solution to Q3. Will `& validate:rules` in the binding ever cause an error if there is no validation rule for that binding? Since the form controls are automatically generated from data, it's easiest to include the binding behavior on all controls whether or not validation rules exist for that entry field.

Comment: It's ok if a property used in an `& validate` binding expression doesn't have any rules associated with it. No exceptions will occur.